# google-glass xe12 update no more js alert or confirm

Tags: webview, google-glass

After update to xe12 my app does not trigger js alerts or confirm dialogs within android webview. Anyone having similar issues with the webview since xe12 update?

Answer (score 0):

XE12 breaks all alert and confirm dialogs, not just in web views, breaking nearly everything. https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=326&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary&start=100